# Making pagination work with multiple tables in Django

Tags: django, pagination

I have a html page in which you can change the table displayed based on the value of a select box. The pagination does not seem to work as intended. When the page is initially loaded the pagination works fine however when changing the the table and trying to go to the next page it loads the second page of the default table.

Here are the relevant parts in the template:

```
<h1 id="tableHeader">Users</h1>
  <div id="template">
    {% include user_table %}
  </div>

<select class="form-select" name="view_select" id="view_select" onchange="loadTable()">
  <option value="1" selected>Users</option>
  <option value="2">Categories</option>
</select>
```

The JavaScript function loadTable:

```
    function loadTable() {
      var select_value = document.getElementById("view_select").value;
      if (select_value == 1) {
        var url = "{% url 'user_table' %}";
      } else if (select_value == 2) {
         var url = "{% url 'category_table' %}";
      } 
      else {
        return;
      }
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
          $("#template").html(response);
        }
      });
    }
```

The url.py file:

```
path('user_table/', views.user_table, name='user_table'),
path('category_table/', views.category_table, name='category_table'),
```

The relevant views:

```
def admin_dashboard(request):
    if (request.user.is_staff == False) and (request.user.is_superuser == False):
        return redirect('landing_page')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # IF CREATE USER BUTTON CLICKED
            if 'create_user' in request.POST:
                form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    user = form.save()
                    return redirect('admin_dashboard')

            # IF CREATE CATEGORY BUTTON CLICKED
            if 'create_category' in request.POST:
                form = AddCategoryForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    category = form.save()
                    category.is_global = True
                    category.save()
                    return redirect('admin_dashboard')

            # IF CREATE CHALLENGE BUTTON CLICKED
            if 'create_challenge' in request.POST:
                form = AddChallengeForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    challenge = form.save()
                    return redirect('admin_dashboard')

            if 'create_achievement' in request.POST:
                form = AddAchievementForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    achievement = form.save()
                    achievement.badge = "badges/custom.png"
                    achievement.save()
                    return redirect('admin_dashboard')

        else:
            # DEFAULT TABLE TO LOAD ON PAGE
            user_table = 'user_table.html'
            user_list = User.objects.all()
            user_paginator = Paginator(user_list, 5)
            user_page_number = request.GET.get('page')
            user_page = user_paginator.get_page(user_page_number)

            user_form = CreateUserForm()
            category_form = AddCategoryForm()
            challenge_form = AddChallengeForm()
            achievement_form = AddAchievementForm()

        return render(request, 'admin_dashboard.html', {'user_page': user_page,'user_table':             user_table,'user_form': user_form, 'category_form': category_form, 'challenge_form': challenge_form, 'achievement_form': achievement_form})

def user_table(request):
  user_list = User.objects.all()
  user_paginator = Paginator(user_list, 5)
  user_page_number = request.GET.get('page')
  user_page = user_paginator.get_page(user_page_number)
  return render(request, 'user_table.html', {'user_page': user_page})

def category_table(request):
  category_list = Category.objects.all()
  category_paginator = Paginator(category_list, 5)
  category_page_number = request.GET.get('page')
  category_page = category_paginator.get_page(category_page_number)
  return render(request, 'category_table.html', {'category_page': category_page})
```

And an example of the html file containing the table that is loaded into the div:

```
<form id="tableform" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Select</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>
    {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
      <th scope="col">Is Admin?</th>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for user in user_page %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <input class = "form-check-input" type = "radio" name = "user_pk" value = {{user.pk}}></input> </th>
    <td> {{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td> {{user.email}} </td>
    {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
      <td> {% if user.is_staff == True %} Admin {% endif %}</td>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    {% if user_page.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item" ><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ user_page.previous_page_number }}" style="color: #525252;">&larr;</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1" style="color: #525252;">1</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    <li class="page-item disabled"><a href='#' class="page-link" style="color: #9c9a9a;">
      Page {{ user_page.number }} of {{ user_page.paginator.num_pages }}
    </a></li>

    {% if user_page.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ user_page.paginator.num_pages }}" style="color: #525252;">{{ user_page.paginator.num_pages }}</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ user_page.next_page_number }}" style="color: #525252;d">&rarr;</a></li></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When the select box is changed to categories, the category table is loaded into the div and when the next page button is pressed, the page reloads with the second page of the user table (the default table loaded onto the page) instead of the second page of the categories table.